# Connecting two surfaces in Blender

Tags: mesh

I am trying to connect 1 with2, I deleted some faces as it was overlapping with other faces " this is a knitted structure). I tried to select vertices and fill as you can see the resulting figure below, there is an inverted normal in black, if I select all faces you can see this the results at 1,2, just fill each surface, is it possible to fill it once a time?

[image]

========= Update======
[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think this might work. In edit mode delete faces 1 and 2. Select all the vertices of 1 and 2. Hit 'w' and select Bridge Edge Loops from the list. Hope this works.

Comment: oops, I forgot to mention I'm still using 2.79.

Answer (score 1):

"W" works in 2.79. In Blender 2.8 select edges by SELECT LOOPS => EDGES LOOPS or manualy and than EDGE => BRIDGE EDGE LOOPS. One thing worth mentioning is that you need to have equal amount of edges on both sides (e. 10 and 10, 16 and 16 etc). Otherwise it won't work. Also delete this face at the end first so that both sides stay quasi "open"...

Comment: Thank you! How to do at 2.79, I am trying find it

Comment: It's in the Ctrl-E Edge menu in 2.79

Comment: @pablographix, I made sure that the same faces, however, you can see in updated post, it seems strange little bit, why the loops isnot activared, although I activiated the add-on